# How to install 32-bit R on Ubuntu 64-bit?

Tags: r, 64-bit, ubuntu-12.04, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

I configured a server with Ubuntu 64-bit and 64-bit R.

After doing all the configuration, one of my libraries to that needed to be loaded into the application R is 32 bits. Now I need to install the 32-bit version of R so that my application to work.

How do I install the 32-bit R without interfirir configuration of all packages already installed and Ubuntu server version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write this command

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

[helper link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/297151/how-to-run-32-bit-programs-on-a-64-bit-system-ubuntu-13-04)

[another link](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-a-32bit-program-in-64bit-ubuntu#.UsYGx9wwdoc)